# ¿Es posible cargar sonidos de una matriz de sonidos en AS3?

Tags: array

Tengo sonidos en la bilblioteca y me gustaría saber si sería posible nombrarlos como 1,2,3.... y poder cargarlos **como si fueran el índice de una matriz**.

Son muchos y dependiendo de los eventos tengo que cargar uno u otro. Si se pudieran **nombrar con los números para la exportación** y luego a la hora de cargarlos hacer referencia al **índice [i]** me evitaría escribir el mismo código 100 veces. Dependiendo del valor de "i" se cargaría un sonido u otro. ¿Es posible hacer esto?

Gracias de antemano

Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

**NOTA:** la solución práctica está con funciones y objetos [java](/questions/tagged/java) pero la técnica será la misma o muy parecida en cualquiera de los lenguajes orientados a objetos habituales.

---

> Si se pudieran nombrar con los números para la exportación

En cuando a renombrarlos, si es para cargarlos no lo necesitas, si tienes los ficheros en el mismo directorio, puedes cargar todos los archivos dinamicamente:

```
File folder = new File("ruta/al/directorio/de/tus/sonidos");
for (File f : folder.listFiles()) {
     // cargar en el array/list de sonidos
}
```

---

> y luego a la hora de cargarlos hacer referencia al índice [i] me evitaría escribir el mismo código 100 veces. Dependiendo del valor de "i" se cargaría un sonido u otro. ¿Es posible hacer esto?

Si, en lenguajes orientados a objetos es posible creando un array o una colección de objetos tipo audio/sonido compatibles con los archivos que tengas.

---

En [java](/questions/tagged/java) puedes usar la clase [**`Clip`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html), depende de lo que quieras `File` también te servirá.

Ya sea bien creando un array `[]`:

```
Clip[] sonidos = new Clip[numeroDeSonidos];
```

O bien un `ArrayList` (con lo que no necesitarás saber el tamaño de antemano ya que son de tamaño dinamico):

```
ArrayList<Clip> sonidos = new ArrayList<>();
```

En ambos casos, puedes iterar a traves de los Clips puedes usar un for-each:

```
for (Clip c : sonidos) {
    c.loop(1); // hacer que suene 1 vez... OJO A QUE SE SOLAPARAN!
}
```

O coger un elemento por la posición:

```
sonidos[posicion];      // array
sonidos.get(posicion)¡; // ArrayList
```